# How to set every data in my ES as non-analyzed?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have a lots of json data in form of json stored in a SQS queue. I have a python script which basically pulls the data from SQS and then indexes it to ES. The code snippet looks like :

```
doc = {
      "settings" : {
      "number_of_shards" : 1
       },
    "mappings" : {
             "_default_":{
                      "_timestamp" : {
                      "enabled" : 'true',
                      "store" : 'true'
                            }
                        }
              }
            }
es = Elasticsearch()
h = { "Content-type":"application/json" }
res = requests.request("POST","http://localhost:9200/"+index_name+"/",headers=h,data=json.dumps(doc))
post = es.index(index=index_name , doc_type='server' , id =1 , body=json.dumps(new_list))
```

So basically my search is not very effective and I read about https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations-and-analysis.html , I basically want to make sure ES doesn't break my data-objects into smaller chunks. What/How can i do to solve this issue ?

Comment: So you want to make every string field in your index as `not_analyzed`.

Comment: yes exactly , i have a lot of data in a central location and that can't be changed . what can be changed is this code which indexes in the ES .

Comment: You will have to re-index your existing data if you want to change the mapping.. Is that possible for you?

Comment: yeah i can.. probably change this source code with something along the lines of `"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"` , not sure if this is the right way of doing so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want every `string` field in your index becomes a `not analyzed` string you need to use [Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html).

```
 PUT index_name
 {
 "mappings": {
  "type_name": {
     "dynamic_templates": [
        {
           "strings": {
               "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
           }
        }
       ]
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: so, if i understand correctly this will only match for `string` and then map/convert them to string ? what does   `"match_mapping_type": "string",` this mean ?

Comment: By default all strings are `analyzed`. this will make all strings not_analyzed.Please note : ** This will not make any change in existing data**. You will have to reindex your existing data.

Comment: by reindex ; do you mean i have to delete my previous index and then reindex the data (new data) ?

Comment: You will have to take backup of existing data, delete the index, create the index with new mapping and then move the data from backup to newly created index. Read https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

Comment: i tried the code as you suggested but still i can see that these fields are analyzed . nothing seems to be changed

Comment: Have you created a new index with these `dynamic mappings`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106611/discussion-between-nishant-singh-and-richa).